# Localstack AWS endpoint in application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, localstack

I would like to run the functional tests for my application which tries to publish a message to AWS SNS. I tried LocalStack and found that it does everything I need to mock and publish messages locally. But my application uses amazon sdk client for java and when I run it locally it still tries to post requests to amazon region instead of the LocalStack

What is the configuration required to make sure that the application interacts with the local stack instead of the AWS URL? Can we specify the endpoint URL in AWS config? I found this to be a open issue in AWS CLI https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1270

Is there any workaround that anyone has implemented for this?

Comment: Use slack webhooks as  middleware

Answer (score 11):

To use your localstack, you have to set your [EndpointConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration.html).

```
AmazonSNS amazonSNS = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
  .withEndpointConfiguration(new EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:4575", "eu-west-1")) 
  .build();
```

You should also use [localstack/localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) instead of [atlassian/localstack](https://github.com/atlassian/localstack) (no longer actively maintained).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JUnit 5 for the tests, let me recommend you [JUnit 5 extensions for AWS](https://madhead.github.io/aws-junit5/asciidoc), a few JUnit 5 extensions that could be useful for testing AWS-related code. These extensions can be used to inject clients for AWS service clients provided by tools like localstack (or the real ones). Both AWS Java SDK v 2.x and v 1.x are supported:

```java
public static class Endpoint implements AWSEndpoint {
    @Override
    public String url() { return "http://localhost:4575"; }

    @Override
    public String region() { return "us-east-1"; }

    @Override
    public String accessKey() { return ""; }

    @Override
    public String secretKey() { return ""; }
}

@ExtendWith(SNS.class)
class AmazonDynamoDBInjectionTest {
    @AWSClient(endpoint = Endpoint.class)
    private AmazonSNS client;

    @Test
    void test() throws Exception {
        Assertions.assertNotNull(client);

        …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you need to add the endpoint configuraton to whichever service you are using (SQS, SNS,etc). **"http://localhost:4575"** didn't work in my case because we need to enable HTTPS endpoints with valid certificates.

The new endpoint which is recommended for AWS services is **"localhost.localstack.cloud:4575"** because the domain is publicly resolvable, and it also publish an SSL certificate that is automatically used inside LocalStack, in order to enable HTTPS endpoints with valid certificates.
The below code worked for me :

```
 String serviceEndpoint =
              String.format("%s:%d", "http://localhost.localstack.cloud", localstack.getMappedPort(4575));
 AmazonSNS amazonSNS =
        AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(
                new EndpointConfiguration(serviceEndpoint,"us-east-1")).build();
```

**Note** : If your system is behind a corporate firewall or an internet service provider, prefer using **localhost** as it does not allow resolving **"localhost.localstack.cloud"** properly.